# Apache 2.4 htaccess - check if request header is present - old SO answers fail

Tags: .htaccess, apache2.4

I have some `.htaccess` configuration directives that serve as "pre-flight" checks before handing the request over to the designated request-handler. I have tried many different approaches to solving this, but due to inconsistencies with Apache versions, many answers simply do not work.

**Relevant .htaccess code:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept} !^$
    RewriteRule ^ - [R=505,L]
</ifModule>
```

**Relevant request headers:**

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,  ...
```

**Server response:**

```
Status Code:505 HTTP Version Not Supported
```

**Conclusion:**
There is something wrong with my condition:
`RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept} !^$`

Your assistance would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Incidentally, I checked one last time if I could solve this; turns out that Apache 2.4 recognizes this specific header as: `HTTP_X_Accept`.

So for anyone facing this same issue, and when you google <- (verb) for this exact issue there are `0` results (yup, i checked) - here is what worked (in the context as stated in the question):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_X_Accept} !^$
```

Comment: It would be nice to have a solution that works across the board, with like an `[AND]` clause? - i don't know how to do that, please feel free to edit this answer, or suggest in comment and i'll update, thanks.